# A map $S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ of degree $0$ extends to $D^n$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-fields

I wanted to understand the proof of this theorem:

> If $M$ is a compact manifold and $\chi(M)=0$, then there is a non-vanishing vector field in M.

I was looking at a post in MathOverflow [about this topic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129752/does-a-connected-manifold-with-vanishing-euler-characteristic-admit-a-nowhere-va/129757#129757), and there is a comment in the accepted answer that says

> Two zeroes of opposite index can be taken to lie in a coordinate chart (because the manifold is connected) and then they can be eliminated using that fact that a map $S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ of degree zero extends to $D^n$.

I understand why the first part of the comment is true, but I'm not sure as to why a map having degree zero allows it to be extended from the boundary to its interior. Furthermore, how does this extension help us in eliminating the zeroes inside the ball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof is rather lengthy, but you can regard this as a special case of Corollary 4.25 in

*Hatcher, Allen*, [**Algebraic topology**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/376089), Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 0-521-79540-0/pbk). xii, 544 p. (2002). [ZBL1044.55001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1044.55001).

This corollary states that the degree map $\pi_n(S^n)\to {\mathbb Z}$ is an isomorphism. In particular, if a map $f: S^n\to S^n$ has zero degree, then it is null-homotopic, equivalently, extends to a map $B^{n+1}\to S^n$.